# Data not showing after importing the sql table into new computer

Tags: php, mysql

I just exported an sql file containing 2 rows because I need to transfer it to a new computer and continue it, after successfully importing the sql files in the new computer, the table in my database is not showing when i try to run my homepage and it just gets this error.

```
0){ echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ echo "
"; echo "
"; echo "\"News\""; echo "
"; echo "
{$row["title"]}
"; echo "
{$row["caption"]}

"; echo "
"; echo "Read More"; echo "

"; echo "
"; echo "
"; echo "
"; } echo "
"; // Free result set mysqli_free_result($result); } else{ echo "No records matching your query were found."; } } else{ echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link); } // Close connection mysqli_close($link); ?>
```

It's working fine in my old computer when I checked it.

Comment: your sql data got imported successfully?did you check the table?

Comment: @lalithkumar yes there are no error, and i can see the data in the field

Comment: Maybe your php.ini file does not permit concatenation of variables in this way. Just a guess, but try outputting the variable alone.

Comment: @Pete tried creating a new database with the same table and field input but it still doesnt show the data and the same error occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: @JayGarrick Pete already gave you an idea...did you try it? What you described doing is unrelated to what was suggested.